# Dynamics CRM Trouble Creating a Record with Javascript/HTML Web Resources

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, crm, microsoft-dynamics

**Update:** This code actually does create the record as desired -- what is confusing though is that the success callback is not fired, but the error callback is. I'm unsure what implications this will have down the road.

I am trying to create a record in dynamics crm using an HTML web resource. The record being created is for a custom entity. The code that should create the record is as follows:

```
function postAnswers () {
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    var odataSetName = "new_regquestionanswersSet"
    var odataUri = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName;

    var answer = {};
    // Define attribute values for the CRM object you want created
    answer.new_name = "Test Answer!";

    //Parse the entity object into JSON
    var jsonAnswer = window.JSON.stringify(answer);
    //Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: odataUri,
        data: jsonAnswer,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            answer = data.d;
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("failure");
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

`postAnswers()` is run on click of a button on an HTML web resource embedded in a form. I am unsure why, but this is coming back as "failure" and the textStatus is "error." Other than that, I'm not getting any blatant errors in the console, which is making it hard to troubleshoot.

Is there any foreseeable reason why this code is failing to create a record? Or why the request is failing? Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Might be worth capturing the traffic with Fiddler, you might get the same "error", but in the past I've also seen additional details exposed.

Comment: Can you send us the "textStatus" error message. I generally starts after looking at this error message.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter in the jQuery error callback is a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which contains a `responseText` property. Have a look at that to see more details about the error.

Note that the `error` and `success` callbacks are deprecated in favor of `fail` and `done` in jQuery 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Excuse my ignorance, but how would I get at that text? I tried including `console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)` in the error callback, but the console prints a blank (weird way to say it, I know. Does not print undefined, but shows nothing on line where console.log executed.) Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That sounds like the correct approach. I tried running your code without any changes, after which XMLHttpRequest.responseText contained a warning that I do not have a new_regquestionanswersSet in my system. 
I changed var odataSetName = "new_regquestionanswersSet" to odataSetName = "AccountSet" and answer.new_name = "Test Answer!" to answer.Name= "Test Answer!". After this the query succeeded. Could you try the same with the default Account entity, and otherwise set a breakpoint in your browser to dig into the jqXHR?

Comment: After changing the code to test with the default Account entity, I experienced the same behavior. What is really confusing me is that the code actually **does** create a new record, but the jQuery ajax call fires the error callback.